# If immediate boss helped get me promoted, is it appropriate to thank the owner as well?

Tags: professionalism, negotiation, promotion

My boss spoke on my behalf to the owner to help me get promoted.

I've decided to take immediate boss out to lunch. But what about the owner? I'd like to get his contributions  recognized.

Do I say anything the owner about the promotion? I was not present during negotiations,so I don't know if it is appropriate to thank the owner somehow as well.

Comment: Why not? Cannot do any harm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I say anything the owner about the promotion? I was not present
>   during negotiations,so I don't know if it is appropriate to thank the
>   owner somehow as well.

It's perfectly appropriate, since it was the owner who ultimately granted your promotion.

A simple "Thank you for the promotion - I love working here and I really appreciate it!" would be both appropriate and welcome, I suspect.